# Blender 2.8 - Edge/face snap doesn't seem to work

Tags: modeling

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8xeH.jpg

My problem is shown in the clip. When I try to snap the vertex onto the edge instead of snapping to it it just goes more or less far depending on where my cursor is along the edge. Same more or less for face snap when I move the lower vertex aswell.

All I am trying to do with this model is extrude the face into the big part in the middle and have them more or less merge. If there is an easy way to do it I would love to hear it, as I've been attempting to solve this problem for multiple days now, and made an account for the sole sake of asking about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? To me it works nicely.

Comment: I am using 2.80